# How to enable Lightning Components in Developer edition?

Tags: salesforce1-app, aura, lightning-aura-components

Documentation says that Lightning components can be enabled in Developer edition after registering a namespace. But Develop --> Lightning Components option is not available. 
Please help.

Comment: Is your developer edition Winter '15?

Comment: @AlexTennant No. Winter 15 updates are not rolled out for my Org (ap1). I need to wait for that!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign up for a Winter '15 Pre-Release Org at 
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter15.jsp

Answer (score 3):

Its not working for existing developer org. Need to register a [new org](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup?d=70130000000lxK7) after registering follow this steps.

```
         - a.   Click Setup | Create | Packages and then click Edit.  
           b.   Click Continue.  
           c.   Type a namespace and then click Check Availability to see if it’s unique. 
           d.   Click Review My Selections and then Save
           e.   From Setup, click Develop | Lightning Components.
           f.   Select the Enable Lightning Components checkbox and click Save.
```

I followed this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/resource/pdfs/Lightning_QuickStart.pdf)  which worked for me.

IRaj

Comment: I created a new Org but Setup --> Develop --> Lightning Components option is not available. I'm using AP1 instance - scheduled date for winter'15 roll out is Oct 18th 2014. I might need to wait till that!!! Thanks for your response

Comment: Hi Vignex, use this link for new dev org registration.  https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup?d=70130000000lxK7

Answer (score 2):

From Winter '16 on, Lightning Components is automatically enabled so you will not see an "Enable Lightning Components" checkbox in setup. However, Lightning App Builder will say that Lightning Components is disabled by default and will not show any custom components or AppExchange components in the org.

You need to create a custom domain under Settings | My Domain and deploy it to all users. Once this is deployed, you'll be able to see Lightning Components in the App Builder, navigate to standalone apps using components, or test them from Dev Console.

Answer (score 0):

I have registered with the pre-release winter 16 link for developer and enterprise edition. But not able to find the link to switch to lightning experience.